# Issue with windows tasks scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I want to run powershell script every day and want to use task scheduler for it. But I have to be log in because this srcipt runs cisco vpn client and putty and then runs some python script for one minute. I don't want it to interrupt my work (because it swichs to different vpn etc.) so I set up time to run this task to 2:00 AM and check "run asap after a scheduled start is missed" to make sure that this task will run every morning after I turn on my computer.

But the problem is, that it doesn't run the script after turn on PC and it says event id 332 - Launch condition not met, user not logged-on. I think I understand this problem, it tries to run this script right after start up so at time I'm not log in. But why does not the task try it after 1 minute again up to 3 times? (see below)

What shoud I do to make sure that it will run every day after turn on PC but only once a day (sometimes I need to restart my PC so I don't want it to run again)

**There is my task configuration:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So I do not know how to achieve that in task scheduler, but You might run the task at logon, but add to Your script something like 

#set variable when script completed successfully 
$atSuccessfullRun=get-date
export-clixml somefile.xml
#check variable on start of script 
$atsuccessfullrun= import-clixml somefile 
 if ($atsuccessfulrun > (get-date).adddays(-1)){your script goes here}

Comment: @Tomek I'm not sure I understand what are you suggesting. I need the script runs automaticaly not manualy.

Comment: Check the `Run whether the user is logged on or not` and `Run with highest privilege` options. That might fix it, I suppose. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I think I tried this too (I tried a lot of combinations :D) but I will try it again.

Comment: Hi, @MartinaZapletalová you have defined the trigger and condition? Because you need that for run automatically

Comment: @VictorSilva yes, the trigger is set up to 2AM daily and condition you can see on picture.

Comment: If you want to make it complicated, you might be able to try running it on startup and in the script have it check whether or not it has been ran in the past 24 hours or something. Not sure if you can request that data or not. You might need to make a file on the machine or a registry entry to keep the last run time that you set when the script runs.

Comment: @MartinaZapletalová What I suggested is to trigger the script at logon , but to add condition on the start of the script, that would prevent it from running if last successful run happened less than 24 hours ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'Run whether the user is logged on or not' and 'Run with highest privilege' options.it will work for you.